# awk regex pattern does not match beginning of the line

Tags: regex, windows, pattern-matching, gawk

I'm using GNU awk version 3.1.7 on Windows 10, MinGW installation.

File to test this has this contents but same behaviour is with other files as well.

**test.txt**

```
line one
second line
another line
end this one should match
double test
yet another
```

I want to print only first words beginning with `e`.

awk command I'm using is:

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^e/) {print $1} }' test.txt
```

But this prints every first word which has character `e` anywhere.

**output**

```
line
second
another
end
double 
yet
```

When I want to match end of the word works fine.
Match every first word ending with `d`.

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /d$/) {print $1} }' test.txt
```

**output**

```
second
end
```

Any idea why first example matching beginning of the word does not work?
What I'm I doing wrong there?

Comment: `awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^e/) {print $1} }'` works fine in my gnu awk version 4.1.4 under Debian 9 (returns only end). Seems something is not good with your awk.

Comment: try `awk '/^e/{print $1}'`, your usage of `if` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Just tried it. Same results, lists every first line with an "e" anywhere.

Comment: @George Vasiliou seems like that is the case. I wish someone with this version of awk could also test for this. I will update it and try again.

Comment: Just to confirm, the file you are operating on was generated in linux and not in Windows?  Try running dos2unix over the file and then use your awk command.

Comment: @grail no file is generated on Windows, I have used Sublime Text on Windows 10.

Comment: I just edited the tags. If you like you can put sum of your comments in a post so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: OK done and deleting all my comments now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's got nothing to do with gawk it's Windows quoting rules. gawk doesn't even see the quotes - it just runs on whatever script Windows passes to it (i.e. the part between the quotes) and it's entirely Windows that interprets the quotes to isolate the script that it then passes to gawk. The standard advice is to avoid the problem is by putting the awk script in a file and running as `awk -f script` instead of trying to deal with the Windows quoting nightmare. The best advice though is to run cygwin on top of Windows.

Comment: It did look very unlikely to me that that is the actual bug in something mature as awk and especially regarding something that important like pattern matching. You are right, quotes are not even part of the awk language that is why there aren't any in the awk script files. I mean quotes around command blocks of course.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with gawk 3.1.6 - 1 on Windows 10.

When I try with single quotes it gives syntax error:

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^e/) {print $1} }' test.txt

//  Error
awk: '{
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

With double quotes works fine, prints only `end`.

```
awk "{ if ($1 ~ /^e/) {print $1} }" test.txt
```

So I have tried this line with double quotes on gawk 3.1.7 as well.
It works.
Prints only `end`.
gawk 3.1.7 does not give any error when I use line example with single quotes but `/^e/` regex in it does not match as it should for some reason.

So at least from my perspective if you are using gawk on windows, always use double quotes for awk code in a command line.

Answer (score 0):

awk "{ if ($1 ~ /^^e/) {print $1} }" test.txt

on Windows platform:
1- exchange " with ' and vice versa
2- for ^ use ^^